# Importing a few instance variables into another class

Tags: python, class, variables, object

So I'm a beginner of Python, and I'm creating a basic text game to learn. I want to import just the *damage*, *speed*, and *range* variables into another file called Player.py where I want to calculate the DPS depending on what type of weapon I have. I tried to create a get_dps method which I wanted to call from my Player.py file, (check inside the comment) but that just threw all kind of exceptions.. Any clues?

Also if anything else in my code is bad feel free to point that out. I want to learn so.

```
from Items import Item


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, desc, value, damage, speed, range):
        self.damage = damage
        self.speed = speed
        self.range = range
        super().__init__(name, desc, value)

    '''
    def get_dps(self, dps):
        self.damage = damage
        self.range = range
        self.speed = speed
        self.dps = dps
        dps = self.damage * self.speed * self.range
        return self.dps
    '''

class Broadsword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name='Broadsword', desc='.', 
              value=10, damage=15, speed=2, range=5)


class Bow(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name='Broadsword', desc='.',
                         value=25, damage=8, speed=5, range=15)


class Dagger(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name='Dagger', desc='.', value=7,
                         damage=5, speed=10, range=2)


class Fists(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name='Fists', desc='.', value=0,
                         damage=1, speed=1, range=1)
```

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. You don't "import the instance variables"; you access the data of the instance that you have.

Comment: I meant that then. So how do I do that? :)

Comment: I think you need to show the code of the player file where you are using these.